# Django changing url by value passed to template

Tags: django, django-urls

This is my first project on Django and what i want to  do is that i have a variable 'a' passed from a view in my template and i am using it like this

```
<a href="{% url 'login:updateComplaint'%}{{a.id}}">
```

to go to a particular url in this case say

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/updateComplaint/4
```

but instead of this my code is sending me to this url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/updateComplaint/0/4
```

Can someone help me fix this If you want any other part of code please comment

Comment: show the relevent section of the urls.py please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the docs on the `url` template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#url

You need to pass the variable from the context as an argument to the template tag, instead of just appending it at the end.

Something like this should work:

```
<a href="{% url 'login:updateComplaint' a.id %}">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things which you can do.

Either make dynamic url with **{{ a.id }}**, like this :

```
<a href="/login/updateComplaint/{{a.id}}">
```

Or pass the a.id as an argument inside your url :

```
<a href="{% url 'login:updateComplaint' a.id %}">
```